# Is it possible to sort by the number of replies?

Tags: support, sorting

When I am in unanswered, it would be nice if I could look at those with 0 replies first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can sort by the number of replies, but you can use the [advanced search operators](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-search-now-61-less-crappy/) and just search for ["answers:0"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0)

Comment: Do you type always that much?

Comment: I try not to, but sometimes I just can't help myself.

Answer (score 1):

[Good enough](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0)?

Comment: But do you have a way of searching in Unanswered -> My Tags for answers: 0?

Comment: [myTag]unanswered:0

Comment: @JS...... Yep:)

Comment: @Lance: you can add tags to the search like `[sql] [jquery]`